# How to use realloc to change the size of memory?

Tags: c, pointers

In my parameters I have

```
uint8_t* const Destination
uint8_t size
```

So I used realloc to change the size of the memory

```
*Destination = realloc(Destination, size);
```

However, this doesn't work and gives a warning.
I'm pretty new at pointers so all help is appreciated.

Comment: Show all of the code—at least a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

```
  uint8_t* const Destination;
```

remove `const`. `const` means that the pointer cannot be changed - and that (change) is exactly what you do

remove the star before the pointer. the program will stop compile because of the const

Comment: For my assignment, I'm not supposed to change any of the parameters. Is there any way to use realloc while the const is there?

Comment: @user12908899: If `Destination` is a parameter and storage needs to be usable by the caller, then `Destination` will need to be of type `uint8_t**`, passed the address of a `uint8_t*`, so that `*Destination` will be of type `uint8_t*`.

Comment: @user12908899, If you have to leave it const, then you shouldn't be trying to change it. // Furthermore, since `Destination` is a parameter, changing its value in the function won't affect the caller, so there's no point in even trying to reallocate it unless you have a way of returning the new pointer to the caller.

Comment: @user12908899 Why do you want the const qualifier?

Comment: @klutt its part of the assignment skeleton, so I'm not supposed to modify it

Comment: Thanks for all the tips, you gave me a couple of ideas.